# DropDownList Items repeat its value after every post-back

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Dropdown shows the below value after binding:

- 1st priority Low
- 2nd priority Medium
- 3rd priority High

Dropdown show the below value after every postback:

- 1st priority Low
- 2nd priority Medium
- 3rd priority High
- 1st priority Low
- 2nd priority Medium
- 3rd priority High

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList1.DataSource = db.ComplaintTypes.ToList();
   DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ct_Name";
   DropDownList1.DataBind();

   cboCpriority.DataSource = db.ComplaintPriorities.ToList();
   cboCpriority.DataTextField = "cp_Desc";
   cboCpriority.DataBind();

   ...
}
```

Comment: post code please?

Comment: You're binding the values each time. Please show us the code.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti check now

Comment: `if(!IsPostBack)...` https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811684/Understanding-The-Complete-Story-of-Postback-in-AS

Comment: Do you check if part of code is PostBack..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use IsPostBack property to only bind during first load, since values will be preserved through view state after that.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = db.ComplaintTypes.ToList();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ct_Name";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        cboCpriority.DataSource = db.ComplaintPriorities.ToList();
        cboCpriority.DataTextField = "cp_Desc";
        cboCpriority.DataBind();
    }
}
```